# Spring Boot and Windows Shutdown

Tags: java, windows, spring-boot

How to receive shutdown events in Spring Boot application on Windows shutdown, windows restart, and windows log off? Currently implemented  context.registerShutdownHook, it works if shutting down the application with ctr+c only.

Any solution, including distributing the app as Windows service, that will provide reliable handling of windows shutdown, will work for me.